# How do I calculate average of score based on their ids from api responses

Tags: javascript, json

Here are the responses from my API:

```
const attractions = [
  {"id": 1,"name": "drive on avenue"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "diving"},
  {"id": 3,"name": "visiting mangroove"},
];

const reviews = [
  {"id": 1,"score": 1.5},
  {"id": 2, "score": 2} ,
  {"id": 3,"score": 5.5},
  {"id": 3,"score": 4},
  {"id": 2,"score": 3},
  {"id": 1,"score": 3.5},
  {"id": 3,"score": 5},
  {"id": 2,"score": 4}
]
```

Expected output:

```
[{"name": "drive on avenue", "score": 2.5},
{"name": "diving", "score": 3},
{"name": "visiting mangroove", "score": 4.83}
]
```

I tried using `reduce`, but that would sum up all scores in one. How can I calculate the average score for each ID?

Comment: Where does `14.5` come from? Did you mean `4.833` instead? Why not use your `reduce` code and instead of calculating the sum, calculate the mean? Just divide by the count.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to take the average of that, Yes it should be 4.83. Thanks for correcting

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the attractions array and for each one, get the average from the reviews array. Something like this:

```js
const attractions = [
    {"id": 1,"name": "drive on avenue"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "diving"},
    {"id": 3,"name": "visiting mangroove"},
  ];
  
  const reviews = [
    {"id": 1,"score": 1.5},
    {"id": 2, "score": 2} ,
    {"id": 3,"score": 5.5},
    {"id": 3,"score": 4},
    {"id": 2,"score": 3},
    {"id": 1,"score": 3.5},
    {"id": 3,"score": 5},
    {"id": 2,"score": 4}
  ]

var returned = []
attractions.forEach((attraction) => {
    let arr = reviews.filter(x => x.id == attraction.id).map(x => x.score);
    let score = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)/arr.length;
    returned.push({ name: attraction.name, score: score});
})

console.log(returned);
```

`map` and `filter` are high-order functions described here:

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

In short, `map` is used here to pull values from an object `{id: 1, score: 3}` => `3`. And `filter` is used here to filter review and get just the id's we want.

Comment: You might want to add some links to the MDN  documentation for those methods.

Comment: Thank you, Sami and Andy! I was using find and then trying to apply map on the returned ids but it didn't work the way I expected. This helps :)

Comment: @Gift366 You're welcome :)